# Regex - Order Multiline SQL String

Tags: c#, regex

Given a string e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](255) NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ADD
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id])

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] ([Id], [Title]) VALUES ('Home', NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](255) NULL
)

...
```

How would i go about ordering the statement so that the CREATE TABLE bits are at the top. I'm guessing i would have to use regular expressions but i'm not sure where i go from there.

I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: You mean whole this is a one string? And you need to spit it and put CREATE parts on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having fun with LINQ.

```
var sql = @"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
            [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
            [Title] [nvarchar](255) NULL
        )

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ADD
            CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id])

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] ([Id], [Title]) VALUES ('Home', NULL)

        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2] (
            [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
            [Title] [nvarchar](255) NULL
        )
        ";
var statementOrder = new[] { "CREATE", "ALTER", "INSERT" };
var statements = from statement in Regex.Split(sql, "\n\r")
              let trimStatement = statement.Trim()
              let statementType = trimStatement.Substring(0, trimStatement.IndexOf(' '))
              orderby Array.IndexOf(statementOrder, statementType)
              select trimStatement;
var newSql = String.Join("\n\r", statements.ToArray());
```

Comment: though it doesnt work properly when there is no space between the CREATE,INSERT,ALTER statements.

Comment: @Anirudha Yes, it depends on the format of the sql string.  Presumably the Regex.Split could be modified to whatever is used to separate statements.

Comment: mine 1 is simple but its pretty tolerant to almost any formatting..:)

Comment: Thanks i prefer this way. I made a small mod to make sure the line breaks were consistent. I replaced every line break/carriage return with a space then i added a line break infront of each statement type (CREATE, ALTER etc) using the following regular expression Regex.Replace(sql, "(" + string.Join("|", statementOrder) + ")", "\n\r$1").

Answer (score 2):

Create a `StringBuilder`

Using `REGEX`

- Extract `TABLE` queries and append to `StringBuilder`
- Extract `INSERT` queries and append to `StringBuilder`
- Extract `ALTER` queries and append to `StringBuilder`

For example you can extract the `Create` queries using this regular expression:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"CREATE .*?(?=(ALTER|INSERT|\z))", RegexOptions.Singleline|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
r.Match("CREATE TABLE [dbo]............");
```

Similarly you can extract `ALTER`, `INSERT` queries by merely replacing the `ALTER`, `INSERT`, `CREATE` words in the above regex.

Comment: @BlackBear it limits the effect else it could include ALTER,INSERT queries...lazy quantifier....

Comment: Thank you :) Have been studying regexes only for some weeks now

Comment: :O C# in a nutshell I love it too

Comment: my favorite 2..it has a nice chapter on REGEX

Comment: Thanks but the Regex doesn't work as it grabs up until the first bracket.

Comment: @nfplee that new expression covers every possibility now!

Comment: Thanks Anirudha but i've accepted Bert's answer simply because i love LINQ :).